# Global symbol "$queryDelete" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to delete data from database using perl CGI but it shows me the error: 
Global symbol "$queryDelete" requires explicit package name at Dbm.pm line 10.

```
package Dbm;
use DBI;
use strict;
use POSIX "fmod";
    sub connection {
         return DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:boys:127.0.0.1" ,'root','');
    };

    sub do_delete {
        my $rData = shift;  
        $queryDelete = " WHERE ";
        my $cWhere = get_condition($rData);
        my $queryDelete="DELETE FROM $rData->{table} $cWhere";      
        my $dbh = connection;
        my $sqlDelete = $dbh->prepare($queryDelete) or die "Can't prepare $queryDelete: $dbh->errstr\n";
        return ($sqlDelete->execute) or die "can't execute the query: $sqlDelete->errstr";
    }
sub get_condition{
    my $rData = shift;
    my $cWhere = " 1=1 ";

    while (my ($key,$value) = each $rData->{condition}) {
        if (ref($value) eq 'ARRAY'){
            $cWhere .= " AND ";

            #print $key.$value->[0];

            my $counter=0;
            foreach my $cValueArray (@{$value}){
                    if(fmod($counter,3)==0) {
                        $cWhere.=" ".$key." ".$cValueArray." ";
                    }
                    else {
                        $cWhere.= " ".$cValueArray. " ";
                    }
                    $counter++;
            }
        }else{
            #print "$key=$value\n

            $cWhere .= " AND ". $key."=". $value;
        }
    };

return $cWhere;
}
1;
```

test.pl

```
 my $q = new CGI();

    my $handle = Dbm::connection();

    sub test_delete{
        my $rData = {
            table     =>'boys',
            condition => {
                ID   => 99,
                Emri => ['<>','\'mon\'','AND','like','\'boy%\''],
            }
        };

        return Dbm::do_delete($rData);
    };
print $q-> start_html(
   -title   => "Main",
   -style   => [ {-src =>'/media/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css', -rel=>'alternate'},
                 {-src =>'/media/css/ui-lightness/mystyle.css', -rel=>'stylesheet', -type=>'text/css'}

   ],
   -script  => [ 
        { -src=>'/media/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'},
        { -src=>'/media/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js' }
   ]
);
print test_delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `strict`. That's good.

```
sub do_delete {
    my $rData = shift;  
    $queryDelete = " WHERE ";
    my $cWhere = get_condition($rData);
    my $queryDelete="DELETE FROM $rData->{table} $cWhere";      
    ...
```

Here you're attempting to use the variable `$queryDelete` (where you assign " WHERE " to it) *before* it's declared with `my`, two lines later. That's bad. You have to declare your variables before you use them.

You could just move the `my` up to your first use of `$queryDelete`, but that *probably* wouldn't be very useful since you'd just overwrite it when you assign a new string to it two lines later.

My guess is you're probably trying to do something like this:

```
sub do_delete {
    my $rData = shift;  
    my $cWhere = get_condition($rData);
    my $queryDelete="DELETE FROM $rData->{table} WHERE $cWhere";      
    ...
```

Comment: it now shows me :Global symbol "%rDataUpd" requires explicit package name at Dbm.pm line 44. for this code :sub _do_update {
 my $rDataUpd = shift;
 my $cQueryUpd = "UPDATE" . " ". $rDataUpd{table} . " " . "SET" . " " ;
 while (my ($keyUpd,$valUpd) = each $rDataUpd->{data}){
  $cQueryUpd .= $keyUpd." = ". " " . $valUpd . " " ;
 };
 
 $cQueryUpd.= " WHERE "; 
    $cQueryUpd.= get_condition($rDataUpd )."<br>";
    return $cQueryUpd;
}

Comment: please can you take a look at this other problem? or do you want me to edit my code?

Comment: @Armida, now you're trying to use a scalar (`$rDataUpd`) as a hash (`%rDataUpd`). I assume it's supposed to be a hash *reference*. So you probably want `$rDataUpd->{table}`

Comment: please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933671/undefined-subroutine-dbconnection-called. I created a new question for this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You didnt define $queryDelete variable in the correct place. You are first using it and defining it afterwards. Try:

```
my $queryDelete = " WHERE ";
...
$queryDelete="DELETE FROM $rData->{table} $cWhere";
```

instead of

```
$queryDelete = " WHERE ";
...
my $queryDelete="DELETE FROM $rData->{table} $cWhere";
```

Comment: now it doesn't show the error but doesn't delete the row i want from database :/

Comment: That will fix the `strict` error but it just causes `$queryDelete` to be pointlessly overwritten.

Comment: You are absolutely right, i was concentrating on the error and overlooked that :)